# Pandas Dividing DF Column Unique Rows by Different DF Unique Mean

Tags: pandas, element, division, calculated-columns

I've been trying to create a column of variability given the mean of the column data values for 'A' and 'B' below. I don't understand how to create the average for each row or element-wise in the panda column by the single data value with the long-term average(s). For example, imagine if have data that looks like this in pandas df1:

```
Year     Name   Data
1999     A      2
2000     A      4
1999     B      6
2000     B      8
```

And, i have a DF with the long-term mean called "LTmean", which in this case is = 3 and 7.

```
mean_df = 
Name    Data mean
0   A          3
1   B          7
```

So, the result would look like this for a new df:   dfnew['var'] = (df1.['Data']/mean_df(???) -1:

```
Year   Name   Var
1999    A     -0.3
2000    A      0.3
1999    B     -0.14
2000    B      0.14
```

Thank you for any suggestions on this! Would a loop be the best idea to loop through each column by the "Name' in each DF somehow using the unique mean_df value for A, B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform` to propagate the results to the original index:

```
df['Var'] = df['Data']/df.groupby(['Name'])['Data'].transform('mean') - 1
```

Output:

```
   Year Name  Data       Var
0  1999    A     2 -0.333333
1  2000    A     4  0.333333
2  1999    B     6 -0.142857
3  2000    B     8  0.142857
```

Comment: hi, thank you - i'm not understanding ".transform('mean')? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You can print `df.groupby(['Name'])['Data'].transform('mean')` to see what it does. It computes the mean by groups, then place `3` where `A` is and `7` where `B` is.

Comment: thank you. 'mean' is not a column name anywhere but "Data mean" is. Is 'mean' referring to a column name or to a function?

Comment: `mean` refers to the function. You can use, e.g. `transform('sum')`.